# Print data from mongodb after button click

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm doing a loan feature here. It works like this: When user enter their pin, their amount and limit will show on the html. I tried using controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Loan",method={RequestMethod.POST})
    @ResponseBody
    public String loan(@RequestBody Loan bank){
        String temp="false";

        String string1 = bank.getPhone();
        String string2 = bank.getLoanpin();
        String string3 = bank.getAmount();
        String string4 = bank.getLimit();
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("phone").is(string1));
        Loan person = mongotemplate.findOne(query, Loan.class);

        String json = "{ 'phone' : '" + string1 +"' , " +""
                + "'loanpin' : '"+ string2 +"'," +
                "'amount' : '" + string3 +"' , " +
                "'limit' : '" + string4 +"' , " +"}";


        if(string1.equals(person.getPhone()) && string2.equals(person.getLoanpin())){
            temp="true";
        }else{
            temp="false";
        }

        return temp;

    }
```

And my html is like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Loan">
    <ion-content class="loginBg">
        <br>
        <center><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Item Img" width="275" height="90"></center>

        <div class="card" >
            <div class="item item-divider site-color text-center">
                Loan Status
            </div>

                <div class="item item-text-wrap text-center row">           

                    <div class="col">
                        <ion-list>
                            <div class="list">
                            <form name="myFormLoan1">
                                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                                    <input type="password" id="loanpin" placeholder="Enter PIN" ng-model="user.loanpin" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="6" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' autocomplete="off">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </ion-list>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <ion-list>
                            <div class="list">
                                <label class="item item-input">
                                    <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="auth(user)">
                                      Check
                                    </button>
                                </label>                      
                            </div>
                        </ion-list>
                    </div>              
                </div>

                <div class="item item-text-wrap text-center row">           
                    <div class="col">
                        <ion-list>
                            <ion-item>
                                Current Loan: <a class = "amount"><br>
                                <span class="loan-color"></span>
                            </ion-item>

                            <ion-item>
                                Loan Limit: <a class = "limit"><br>
                                <span class="site-color"></span>
                            </ion-item>
                        </ion-list>             
                    </div>              
                </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive">
        <center><button class="button button-positive" ng-click="newloan()"> New Loan </button></center>
    </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

So when i clicked the button, it was supposed to print the amount and limit. But before that, controller will check user's phone number and pin. Javascript is like this:

```
$scope.auth = function(user) {

            var formdata = {
                   phone :  $("#phone").val(),
                   loanpin : $("#loanpin").val(),
                   amount : $("#amount").val(),
                   limit : $("#limit").val(),
            }

            var Jformdata = JSON.stringify(formdata);

            console.log(Jformdata);

            $.ajax({

                url : "/ProjectSinarmas/Loan",
                context : document.body,
                type : 'POST',
                data : Jformdata,
                dataType : 'json',
                contentType : "application/json"
            }).done(function (response){

                console.log(response);
                if(response == "true"){
                    $(".amount").html(amount);
                    $(".limit").html(limit);
                }else if(response == "false"){
                    $scope.showAlert('Wrong PIN, please check again!');
                }

            });
        };
```

So my question, how do i print the data on mongodb to my html? Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen how do i print my data after the validation on mongodb to my html